# Visual Studio utf-8 error

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

Tentei usar o Visual Studio junto com as ferramentas para `Python`, porém, quando coloco:
`print("Hello World")`
e aperto `F5` ele roda sem problemas.

Porém, quando boto:
`print("olá")` ele da o seguinte erro:

> ```
> File "C:\Users\.... path .....\PythonApplication1\PythonApplication1.py", line 1
> SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe1 in position 0:
>  unexpected end of data
> Press any key to continue . . .
> ```

Gostaria de saber como resolver!

Comment: Você salvou o código em Ansi/Win-1252 em vez de UTF-8. Verifique o encoding usado nas opções de salvar do editor.

Comment: Muito Obrigado meu amigo!

Answer (score 1):

Tenta isso:

```
#coding: UTF-8
print('olá')
```

Dependendo da versão do Python, deve ser especificado a codificação usada caso queira usar caracteres especiais. Se não funcionar, tente também isso:

```
#coding: latin-1
print('olá')
```