# Erro de acentuação na saída do Visual Studio

Tags: python-3.x, visual-studio-2017

```
print('Olá Python!)
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Segue algumas informações, sobre a configuração de meu PC.

- Windows 10 Pro
- Cmder
- Página de código ativa: 850

Comment: Qual versão do python tá usando?...

Comment: @Tuxpilgrim É a versão 3.7.0

Answer (score 4):

Segue abaixo em detalhes o que deu certo.

Trata-se de editar o settings.json e em code-runner.executorMap, adicionar a seguintes linhas:

```
"code-runner.executorMap": {
    "python": "set PYTHONIOENCODING=utf8 && python"
}
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 3):

Você provavelmente esta usando a o [character encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_encoding) errado.

Sua pergunta provevelmente é [duplicada](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/156178/visual-studio-utf-8-error) mas vou responder da melhor forma possível. 
Para compreender bem o que lhe ocorre de uma olhada no post [Quais as principais diferenças entre Unicode, UTF, ASCII, ANSI?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/156951/quais-as-principais-diferen%C3%A7as-entre-unicode-utf-ascii-ansi)
, e para fechar o assunto, vale a pena também ler [esse artigo](https://www.ime.usp.br/~pf/algoritmos/apend/unicode.html).

Mas para resolver de forma rápida seu problema vou citar um ultimo artigo do [SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/840065/how-to-change-source-file-encoding-in-csharp-project-visual-studio-msbuild-ma) no qual demonstra um guia simples para mudar o encoding em seu Visual Studio:

> - open the problematic file in Visual Studio.
> - on the File menu click “Advanced Save Options“
> - from “Encoding” combo select “Unicode (UTF-8 …“
> - click OK.

Selecione o tipo de encoding que lhe atende, ou seja UTF-8.

Comment: Eu já fiz esta alteração e não surtiu efeito. A codificação consta como UTF-8, tanto na barra de status quanto nas configurações de Encoding. Obrigado!

Comment: Continua a mostrar o mesmo erro ?

Comment: Acabei de testar uma outra solução que me foi passada e deu certo. Trata-se de editar o settings.json e em code-runner.executorMap, adicionar a seguintes linhas:                                                                                                                               
                                                                                                           "code-runner.executorMap": {
        "python": "set PYTHONIOENCODING=utf8 && python"
    }

Answer (score 0):

A solução do Marcio funcionou aqui...
O settings.json ficou assim:

```
{
    "python.jediEnabled": false,
    "editor.minimap.enabled": false,
    "breadcrumbs.enabled": false,
    "files.autoSave": "afterDelay",
    "python.pythonPath": "C:\\Users\\Leandro\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37-32\\python.exe",
    "editor.accessibilitySupport": "off",
    "workbench.startupEditor": "newUntitledFile",
    "editor.suggestSelection": "first",
    "vsintellicode.modify.editor.suggestSelection": "automaticallyOverrodeDefaultValue",
    "code-runner.executorMap": { "python": "set PYTHONIOENCODING=utf8 && python" }
}
```